# trying to position two buttons to the left and right of a parent div

Tags: html, css, owl-carousel

I'm using the [owl carousel 2](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/) plugin and I'm having issues trying to place the prev and next buttons to the right and left of the scroller.  I'm using the navContainer argument allowing me to use a custom nav controller.

The current navContainer looks like this:

```
#customNav {
  position:absolute;
  top: 0px;
}

#customNav .owl-prev {
  top: 55px;
  left: -20px;
}
#customNav .owl-next {
  top: 55px;
  right: -20px;
}
```

I'm trying to place the left controller on the left of the carousel and the next controller to the right.

Here is my current code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thetoolsmith/6va39or7/21/)

Any idea what I'm missing? Should the navController container be relative?

Comment: First I added the wrong code but now I have a working demo. Please view my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me some time but I fixed it.

This is the [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6va39or7/22/).

This did the trick:

```
#customNav {
    position:absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
}

#customNav .owl-prev {
    float:left;
    margin-left: 0.9375rem;
}
#customNav .owl-next {
    float:right;
    margin-right: 0.9375rem;
}
```